# Simplification of Derivation

Tags: calculus, tangent-line, cycloid

I'm a high school student and I am writing a paper on cycloids. To solve for the tangent to the curve at any point I use pythagoras. I understand that - however I came across this simplification and I cannot explain why this is so.

ds = (dx^2 + dy^2)^(1/2)

ds = (1 + y^2)^(1/2) dx

Comment: $ds=(dx^2+dy^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ then multiply and divide by dx, then you have:$$ds=\frac{\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}}{dx}dx=\sqrt{\frac{dx^2}{dx^2}+\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}}dx=\sqrt{1+y'^2}dx$$

Comment: That's what I get, too - so y needs to be y' i.e. the answer is wrong?

Comment: the correct is y', note that:$\frac{dy}{dx}=y'$